# Mod_rewrite - redirect old urls to the new ones

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for a solution to redirect old urls (e. g. `aboutme.php`) to the new ones (same `/about-me`).

The problem is: if I'll go to `example.com/aboutme.php`, the user is not redirected to pretty url (`/about-me`). Adding R=301 doesn't help - it makes `/about-me` redirect to `aboutme.php`.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^about-me$ /aboutme.php [L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /portfolio.php [L]
RewriteRule ^motion$ /motion.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-thanks$ /contact_thanks.php [L]



</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make it in the other direction.

If you want to rewrite aboutme.php to about-me

you should use

```
RewriteRule ^aboutme.php /about-me [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

The place /about-me has to be present. If not, you can redirect this virtual place to a file (say rewrite.php) which gets the actual file from database or some configuration. Place the following rules at the bottom of your htaccess rules.

```
#don't rewrite the rewrite script
RewriteRule rewrite.php - [L]

#as example don't rewrite the image folder
RewriteRule ^images - [L]

#everything else that doesn't match a rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

after that you can access your requested virtual file in rewrite.php with `$_GET['file']`.

EDIT:

your rewrite.php could look like this: (this is the simplest way todo. but you have to do some error checking etc.)

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$config = array(
    'about-me' => 'aboutme.php'
);
include($config[$file]);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, now server tells me that 'The requested URL /about-me was not found on this server'.

Comment: ok, lets suppose you go to aboutme.php -> you get redirected to /about-me which does not exist. so you have to create a rule to match this and display the right content. do you have the same file structure as before?

Comment: Where should I put this rewrite.php rule? At the bottom of the .htaccess? Do I need to change variables?

Comment: You have to put the three additional lines after all your rules. But be carefull, you also have to specify all your directorys your images, css and javascript etc. are in. e.g. say /image -> you have to define a rule `RewriteRule ^images - [L]` before the last line.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but this is too complicated for me. Every tutorial on the internet contains only basic rewrite rules. So in the reality same rewrite rules aren't enough?

Comment: my answer are basic rewrite rules too. but a little bit combined. first, you rewrite `/aboutme.php` to `/about-me`, but this is only virtual so you rewrite to some file which then includes the right file for you. because you can't rewrite `/about-me` back to `aboutme.php` (endless loop). (And the options [L] stands for last, [R=301] stands for permanent redirect, [QSA] stands for append query string (GET))

Comment: Thanks for the details :) I think I can live with `/pretty` and `pretty.php`. However, my biggest concern is SEO - I hope that if I won't put any direct `.php` links, Google robots won't crawl them.

Comment: yeah, google won't crawl a site which isn't linked somewhere. so if you stay with your SEO friendly name everything should be ok.